# Cannot edit in input react

Tags: reactjs

I am making an update form for user but I can't type in input tag when I added `handleChange`

Here is my code base:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // Update state
    updatePlayersData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
    <input
      value={title}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder={title}
      pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
      minLength="1"
      maxLength="20"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're setting your inputs  value to `title` variable everytime and not updating your title value.

```js
    <input
      value={title} // you are not updating title value and using it on your value
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder={title}
      pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
      minLength="1"
      maxLength="20"
    />
```

as I understand it, you want to specify a default value. Try this one:

```js
    <input
      defaultValue={title} // now it will change when you update input string
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder={title}
      pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
      minLength="1"
      maxLength="20"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly provide `name="name_of_field"` property to input element.

It will assign the input to the specified `name_of_field` and you can, later on, use it as `input.name_of_field`

Answer (score 0):

In your code `input` doesn't have any `name` attribute. But in `onChange` method the state is being updated based on the `name` of the input. Hence, the changes are not getting reflected in the input.

So by adding `name="title"` attribute to the `input` and providing `value={data.title}` should work. Below I have added a snippet for the same

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
  
  return <input
      value={data.title}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder={data.title}
      pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
      minLength="1"
      maxLength="20"
      name="title"
    />
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Note: I have replaced `updatePlayersData` with `setData` for the example purpose. Also, in your code as per your requirement you can add any `name` for the input. But then make sure the same prop in the data to be passed as value to the input.